# How to tell which file came from which input?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have two file input controls on my view. In my controller the first parameter is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> documentFiles` and all this is working perfectly.

The only problem is I don't know which file came from which file input control. Maybe if there are two files added they will be in the order the controls were presented... or maybe they are in the order the user added them? I can test and find this out, but another issue would also be if only one file is uploaded (both fields are optional).

Off the top of my head, the only solution I can think of would involve creating a hidden field that tracks which inputs have been populated (and, possibly, track the order in which they are populated as well if that determines the order in which they are received).

Surely there is a more "correct" way to handle this though that I must be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it does put the files in the order the controls are displayed, and to my pleasant surprise it actually includes a null entry in the list if there is no file. So there will always be two entries and I can determine which is which file based on its position.